# how does bootstrap login page Sign in button work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

as I open the bootstrap page of login, "http://v3.bootcss.com/examples/signin/", 
when I click the "Sign in" button, It will show me a prompt. But I can't find the prompt text.

How does the prompt work? What has happened after I click the "Sign in" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not Bootstrap that is performing the validation of the fields.
Its HTML5 that is validating the fields that have the attribute `required`

Have a look at [this JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pr2asf16/)

```
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
```

Comment: As the prompt text is also from the JQuery? In my web, I don't want to use the "submit" type, how can I let the check work?

Comment: Sorry it is not JQuery, but HTML5 itself that is validating. 
HTML5 has other attributes that you can use as well.